# 'position: absolute; bottom: 0' does not work when parent position is relative

Tags: css, position

I have a css code.

Why the `bottom: 0` does not work when the `position: relative;`?

If I give up `position: relative;`, the `bottom` works but `float: left` and `float: right` are not at `width: 930px;`.

sorry my bad english

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 930px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    Right
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    Bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's because when you're setting `position:relative` on main, then `position:absolute` will be *relative* to the parent. And your `#main` div has no height, which causes the `#bottom` to not be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: i want height is end of #left what need i do?

Comment: @user52878 I'd recommend trying to learn about CSS positioning: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

Comment: so what is the fix? You stated the source of the issue

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way to go, use `float` for such type of layout.

Coming back to your question,

`bottom:0` is working fine but since your main doesnt have height, you are not seeing it,

Do this for `#main`,

```
    #main
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 930px;
        padding:10px;
        margin:0 auto; 
        height:200px;
    }
```

**Edit**:

You can use,

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

#left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#right {
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
}

#bottom {
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```

but I wont recommend this ( I said earlier this layout should not be handled by `float`) 
`absolute` does not account for `position` of other elements, so this code will break if `#left` has more height.

If I were you, I would have used this,

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

#left {
    float:left;
}

#right {
  float:right;
}

#bottom {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: i want height is end of #left what need i do?

Comment: What do you mean by end of `#left` ?

Comment: I want to "#bottom" at the bottom of the "#left".

Comment: I've updated my answer, do look at it. As you said your English is not so good, do let me know if you dont get something.